# Export to pug/jade instead of html

Tags: javascript, webpack, pug-loader

Is it possible to have webpack output to a jade/pug file instead of html? Every package i have found does the opposite, jade/pug -> html.

Currently I just convert `/dist/index.html` to jade using html2jade.com after running `npm run build`, but i would like to skip a step and just have webpack output it in jade

Comment: you want to convert html to pug?

Comment: When running `npm run build` to build my webpack project, i want it to build an index.jade instead of an index.html in the `/dist` folder.

Comment: What are you building it from?

Comment: There's this plugin, sounds like what you need (but i haven't tried it): https://github.com/negibouze/html-webpack-pug-plugin